# Could not resolve argument $encoder of "xx", UserPasswordEncoderInterface, Symfony 4.*

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

I'm trying to encode the password im passing through post but it is giving me an error when I declare the argument in the function.

> Could not resolve argument $encoder of "App\Controller\UsuarioController::altapropietario()", maybe you forgot to register the controller as a service or missed tagging it with the "controller.service_arguments"?*

Here I paste the whole function, it has a form and its just for registering new users.

```php
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class UsuarioController extends AbstractController
{
    public function altaPropietario(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder )
    {

        $propietario = new Usuario();

        $form = $this->createForm(AltaPropietarioType::class, $propietario);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted())
        {
            $propietario->setRole("ROLE_PROP");

            $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($propietario, $propietario->getPassword());
            $propietario->setPassword($encoded);
            // rest of the implementation not included.
        }
    }
}
```

My security yml is the following:

```
security:
encoders:
    App\Entity\Usuario: bcrypt


# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    users_in_memory: { memory: null }
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: lazy
        provider: users_in_memory

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

services.yaml:

```
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
```

Comment: Is your controller located in `src/Controller/`? Could you also show your `config/services.yaml` (the section with `App\` and `App\Controller` in particular)?

Comment: Sorry for the late response @dbrumann , my controller indeed is located there, and the config/services.yml is the same as the base one. I finally corrected it renaming the function to register(). Nevertheless, I still dont know why it didn't work.   PS. I ll edit the question adding the services.yml. Thanks

Comment: do you have encoder in security.yaml for this class?

Comment: This is odd indeed. The tag `controller.service_arguments` is clearly set and it should be able to infer the right encoder based on the interface. Can you use `bin/console debug:autowiring UsuarioController` (or `debug:container`) to check if the controller is registered correctly as a service